# C# Forms - Custom Button

Tags: c#, .net, forms, inheritance, controls

I have a button with a particular style that I'm reusing within multiple user controls of my project. Whenever I want to change the visual style of this button, I must repeat the property changes everywhere it is being used, which is a pain.

I would like to "extend" the default Button control so that I can reuse it at design-time, within the designer, without having to change its style everywhere. I.e I would like to have my ExtendedButton pickable from the toolbox.

I would also like to be able to open this extended button in the designer so that I can change its design using the designer, causing it to be changed everywhere it is being used.

I tried to cdo the following, but the designer won't show anything and says "To add components to your class, drag them from the Toolbox..."

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestForm
{
    [Designer(typeof(Button))]
    public partial class ExtendedButton : Button
    {
        public ExtendedButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }
    }
}
```

How could I acheive this please ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it to work.

I have to remove the [Designer(typeof(Button))] that I added and call the base constructor that wasn't called by default when creating a new UserControl file.

```
public partial class ExtendedButton : Button
{
    public ExtendedButton() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your stile global for all extended buttons you can use static variable:

```
class ExtendedButton : Button
{
    public enum ExtendedStyle
    {
        Red,
        Blue
    }

    private static ExtendedStyle style;
    public ExtendedStyle Style
    {
        get { return style; }
        set { style = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);

        if (style == ExtendedStyle.Red)
            pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
        else
            pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
    }
}
```

If you change Style in designer all buttons will change their style